# Angular custom directive not loading boostrap nav bar collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i am currently having some trouble making my side bar items collapse and not showing their options, it seems like the collapse fuction does not load at all

Here is my custom directive

```
  app.directive('ngSparkline', function() {
    return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: 'menu.html'
  }
});
```

This is the directive html

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">I T B S - Intranet</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks " >
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <h4 class="text-center"><strong>Prestaciones disponibles</strong></h4>
                                        <div class="divider"></div>
                                        <h4 class="text-center">3123123 Bsf.</h4>
                                        <ng-menu></ng-menu>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="historialpagos.html">
                                <strong>Ver historial de pagos</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                 <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down "></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- /.Solicitudes de vacaciones -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Solicitud 1</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted"><div><strong>Desde:</strong>01/01/2001 </br><strong>Hasta:</strong>02/02/2002</div></span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                                          Aceptada
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Solicitud 2</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted"><div><strong>Desde:</strong>03/03/2003 </br><strong>Hasta:</strong>04/04/2004</div></span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%">
                                          En proceso
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Solicitud 3</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted"><div><strong>Desde:</strong>05/05/2005 </br><strong>Hasta:</strong>06/06/2006</div></span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
                                            Rechazada
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="historialdevacaciones.html">
                                <strong>Ver historial de vacaciones</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.Solicitudes de vacaciones -->
                </li>

                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> {{"Angular User"}}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">

                        <!--Menu modulo de perfil de empleado-->
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Perfil del empleado<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="perfilempleado.html">Consultar datos de empleado</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="actualizardatospersonales.html">Actualizar datos personales</a>
                                </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Actualizar datos profesionales<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">Cursos</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">Certificaciones</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">Estudios</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">Experiencia laboral</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#">Conocimientos</a>
                                                </li>

                                        </ul>
                                    <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                                </li>                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>

                        <!--Menu modulo de vacaciones-->
                        <li >
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-fw"></i> Gestion de control <span class="fa arrow"></span> de vacaciones</a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="solicitatvacaciones.html">Solicitar vacaciones</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="historialdevacaciones.html">Ver historial de solicitudes de vacaciones</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>

                        <li >
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Pagos <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="historialpagos.html">Ver historial de pagos</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>

                         <li >
                            <a href="generardocumentos.html"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Documentos</a>

                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

  <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

In the main html file i did place the following script tags

```
 <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```